# show that $\lim(\pi(x)/x) = 0$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I need to show that:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(\pi(x)/x) = 0$$ Where $\pi(x)$ is the number of primes smaller then $x$.

I tried using the fact that:
$$\pi(x)<(1-1/2)(1-1/3)...(1-1/k)X + O(1)$$
but didn't get anywhere.
any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe:
$$ \pi(x)\leq\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)\cdot\ldots\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{p_k}\right)x +O(1), $$
that is enough to prove your statement, since:
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_k}\right) = 0 $$
is a consequence of:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{p_k}=+\infty. $$
The last point can be proved in many ways (see Erdos, *Proofs from the Book*), but partial summation together with the Chebyshev lower bound is a common choice. Another common choice is to prove it is essentially equivalent to $\lim_{s\to 1^+}\zeta(s)=+\infty$ through the Euler product for the $\zeta$ function.

Comment: You can also bypass Chebyshev's bound by assuming to the contrary that $\limsup \pi(x)/x > 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Chebyshev proved with elementary methods (and of course without using PNT) that
$$
\frac{\pi (x)}{x}\le c\frac{1}{\log (x)}
$$
for all $x\ge x_0$, and constant $c\sim 1.10555$. For $x\to \infty$ the claim follows. We may take $x_0=96098$, see [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CEYQFjAEahUKEwjz-Nu364LGAhXJGCwKHY9LDr4&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhomepage.univie.ac.at%2FDietrich.Burde%2Fpapers%2Fburde_23_cheby_error.pdf&ei=cfp2VbP8IMmxsAGPl7nwCw&usg=AFQjCNF3qTqD1hUKkz_8I9J7ecxyyc3vPg&bvm=bv.95039771,d.bGg).