# Analysis of Prime Number Theorem

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Assume that we do not know Prime Number Theorem yet. 
Then

> What is the limit of $\frac{\pi(x)}{x}$ as $x \to \infty$. I feel that is should go to $0$, but I am not sure about that. How should I find that out. May be we should bound it above by some function. How should I proceed with that?

$\pi$ is the prime counting function.

Answer (score 2):

Applying the [sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to $[1,x]$ sieves out roughly $\frac1p$ of the numbers for each prime $p$. More specifically, as $x\to\infty$, the proportion of numbers sieved out in the step for prime $p$ converges to $\frac1p$. (If this is not obvious, you can prove it by applying the Chinese remainder theorem to the product of all primes up to and including $p$.) Thus, the proportion of numbers remaining can be made arbitrarily close to $\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1-\frac1{p_i}\right)$ for arbitrary $n$ (where $p_i$ is the $i$-th prime). But

\begin{eqnarray}
\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1-\frac1{p_i}\right)
&=&
\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\log\left(1-\frac1{p_i}\right)\right)
\\
&\le&
\exp\left(-\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{p_i}\right)
\\
&\to&
0
\end{eqnarray}

for $n\to\infty$, since [the sum of the reciprocals of the primes diverges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes). Since the primes are a subset of the numbers that remain after $n$ sieving steps, it follows that

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pi(x)}x=0\;.
$$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: By the elementary Chebyshev estimate we have
$$
\frac{c_1}{\log(x)}<\frac{\pi(x)}{x}<\frac{c_2}{\log(x)}
$$
for all $x\ge x_0$ and constants $0<c_1<1$, $c_2=\frac{6}{5}c_1$. See [here](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/dietrich.burde/papers/burde_23_cheby_error.pdf) for references.

At this site, the question has been answered here: [show that $\lim(\pi(x)/x) = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318555/show-that-lim-pix-x-0)